Cloud Masking and Compositing Landsat SR Timeseries in GEE Python Colab - Fails to Export
I'm trying to create a seasonal (dry/wet) Landsat NDVI time series for multiple sites in an area over a span of approximately 30 years within Google Earth Engine's Python Colab. Each site will have a 3x3 pixel area of coverage. At each site, I want to create a cloud mask with the QA PIXEL band as I think that's more efficient than filtering by CLOUD_COVER since that takes into account the entire scene which could reduce available images. The final products will be several geotiffs of median NDVI values of each image collection.
Below is a script for running a subset of the actual data needed so I can quickly assess the success of the script. The final script will include Landsats 5-8 with their respective bands.
# Define a function to create a cloud mask using the QA band
def maskClouds(image):
    # Select the QA band
    qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
    # Create a mask to exclude cloudy pixels
    cloud_mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).eq(0)
    # Apply the mask to the image
    return image.updateMask(cloud_mask)


# Define the Landsat image collection (Landsat 7)
landsat_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')

# Define the site coordinates for PntID 17
pnt_id = 17
lat = -17.542346
lon = 140.801623

redBand = 'SR_B3'
nirBand = 'SR_B4'

# Define the point geometry
point = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat)

# Define the area of interest as a buffer around the point
area_of_interest = point.buffer(30)  # Assuming 30m resolution, 30m buffer = 3x3 pixel area

# Loop over years for dry seasons
for year in range(2011, 2014):
    # Print processing message
    print(f"Processing for year {year}")

    # Date range
    start = f"{year}-05-01"
    end = f"{year}-10-31"

    # Load imagery, filter by date and cloud coverage, and map NDVI calculation
    image_collection = landsat_collection.filterDate(start, end)
    masked_collection = image_collection.map(maskClouds)
    ndvi_collection = masked_collection.map(addNDVI)

    # Export NDVI image to Google Drive as GeoTIFF
    export_task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
        image=ndvi_collection.median(),
        description=f"Flinders_{year}_medianNDVI_mask_PntID{pnt_id}",
        folder="Flinders_17",  # Specify your folder name
        region=area_of_interest,
        scale=30,
        maxPixels=1e13,
        skipEmptyTiles=True,
        crs='EPSG:4326',
        fileFormat='GeoTIFF')

    export_task.start()

    collection_size = ndvi_collection.size().getInfo()
    print("Number of images in the collection:", collection_size)

  print("Processing complete!")

I'm hoping that I've done the mask correctly. I'm unsure how to check that. My main issue is that the script runs but never exports anything. I've checked the number of images in the collection with the print statement and it does result will images. Am I missing something?
